# Find the categories that frequently occur together based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-cleaning

Consider that I have the following data in a Pandas dataframe:

| Paper ID | Author ID |
| --- | --- |
| Paper_1 | Author_1 |
| Paper_1 | Author_2 |
| Paper_2 | Author_2 |
| Paper_3 | Author_1 |
| Paper_3 | Author_2 |
| Paper_3 | Author_3 |
| Paper_4 | Author_1 |
| Paper_4 | Author_3 |

I need to find the number of non-zero collaborations. So, the output should be:
(Author_1,Author_2) --> 2
(Author_1,Author_3) --> 1

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is fairly small, then merging on the `Paper ID` will generate pairs that can be collapsed/aggregated:

```py
# assume df has columns Paper ID, Author ID
df_merged = df.merge(df, on="Paper ID")

# keep only one instance of a collaboration
mask = df_merged["Author ID_x"] > df_merged["Author ID_y"]

# aggregate (note the use of the mask to avoid double-
# counting and self-collaborations as noted in the
# comment by Riccardo Bucco)
counts = (
    df_merged[mask]
    .groupby(["Author ID_x", "Author ID_y"])
    .agg(collaboration_count=("Paper ID", "count"))
)
```

Comment: Close to 35,000 rows.

Comment: That's reasonably small, should be able to run it in memory within a minute or so.

Comment: You're returning also self-collaborations and both collaborations between A and B, and B and A

Comment: Good point, let me fix that. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: Nice way to get rid of useless collaborations, thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for this. It works.